# Django password_reset url and password_reset_confirm

Tags: django

**accounts/urls.py**

```
 password_reset_dict =   {
                    'template_name': 'registration/reset_password.html',
                    'email_template_name': 'registration/password_reset_email.hmtl',
                    'html_email_template_name': 'registration/password_reset_email.html',
                    'subject_template_name': 'registration/password_reset_subject.txt',
                    'password_reset_form': EmailValidationOnForgotPassword,
                    }
```

and so...

```
path('sifre-sifirla/', PasswordResetView.as_view(), password_reset_dict, name='password_reset'),
re_path('sifre-sifirla/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/',PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
```

**password_reset_email.html**

```
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
```

returns url as:

`http://localhost:8000/uye/yeni-sifre/MTU/**set-password**/`

The question is, how to change `**set-password**` to my native language?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Django allows to specify *translatable* URLs: https://djangobook.com/internationalization-url-patterns/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to do this at the moment. There's an open ticket [#28780](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28780) to add this feature.

Comment: Thank you for the information, so we will wait till feature releases.